# How to get a push notification at a set time? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift3, push

I'm making an app that's supposed the user everyday at a set time about the news. It get's the text of the news through a function which calls it from an array. My question is: how do I get my app to call the function and then send me a push notification with the info text every day at, let's say, 4am?

Thanks to everyone for answering! Have a great day!

Comment: If you want to use a push notification, then you need to run a process on a server somewhere. You can schedule a local notification to be delivered at a specific time, but the test is set at the point when the notification is scheduled, not when the notification is delivered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code I used before. Not a hundred-percent what you are looking for, but I hope useful for you.

You need to modify it to be sending daily

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
 
class ViewController: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    var isGrantedNotificationAccess:Bool = false
    @IBAction func send10SecNotification(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if isGrantedNotificationAccess {
            //add notification code here
         
            //Set the content of the notification
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "10 Second Notification Demo"
            content.subtitle = "From MakeAppPie.com"
            content.body = "Notification after 10 seconds - Your pizza is Ready!!"
         
            //Set the trigger of the notification -- here a timer. 
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(
                timeInterval: 10.0,
                repeats: true)
         
            //Set the request for the notification from the above
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(
                identifier: "10.second.message",
                content: content,
                trigger: trigger
            )
         
            //Add the notification to the currnet notification center
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
         
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
            self.isGrantedNotificationAccess = granted
        }
    }
}
```